# react dom traverself or parent div targeting?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following in React (using redux):

```
....
deleteBase(title) {
        this.props.dispatch(removeBase(title));
    }

    render() {
      const baseList = this.props.bases.map(base => {
        return (
          <li key={base.title} className="base">
            <Link to={base.title}>{base.title}</Link>
            <i
              className="fas fa-times"
              onClick={title => this.deleteBase(title)}
            />
          </li>
        );
      });
    }
```

In the dispatch function of `removeBase` I will need to have access to the single base.title from the clicked element. No matter how I try to get the right title transferred over to the function I can't do it.

```
return (
    <ul className="baseWrapper">
        {baseList}
        <li className="add-list-wrapper">
            <AddBase type="base" onAdd={title => this.addBase(title)} />
        </li>
    </ul>
);
```

Comment: Are you *returning* `baseList` from `render`...?

Comment: yes, i just shortened it a bit. i will update the above